# Issue with React Component Rendering and State Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

Description of the Problem:

I'm building a React component that fetches data from an API and updates the state. However, I'm facing an issue with rendering and state updates.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
            const result = await response.json();
            setData(result);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Data:</h1>
            {data.map(item => (
                <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Error Messages:

No specific error messages, but the data is not rendering as expected, or the state is not updating after fetching.

Comment: What does the console / network tab show? Does your API request receives JSON?

Comment: Try logging the response. Also you dont need await in response.json()

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, the API `https://api.example.com/data` doesn't seem to be working. So I modified your code to use an API that's working.

Also made a tiny adjustment to check if the length of `data` is greater than zero before rendering the content of your data.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://api.tvmaze.com/people");
      const result = await response.json();
      setData(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
  };


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Data:</h1>
              {data.length === 0
                ? "loading..."
                : data.map((item) => <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: OP hid  URL by putting api.example.com

Comment: oh!! shoot! Thanks for pointing that out.